# Can't use WPF designer in VS2008 SP1

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2008-sp1

i searched several hours four solution and nothing found. If I open WPF Designer in my VS2008 Team Suite SP1 I become following error:

> Loading this assembly would produce a
>   different grant set from other
>   instances. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131401)    at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
>   type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean&
>   bNeedSecurityCheck)    at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean fillCache)    at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean
>   fillCache)    at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type
>   type, Boolean nonPublic)    at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags
>   bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[]
>   args, CultureInfo culture, Object[]
>   activationAttributes)    at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type
>   type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder
>   binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo
>   culture, Object[]
>   activationAttributes)    at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(String
>   assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean
>   ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr,
>   Binder binder, Object[] args,
>   CultureInfo culture, Object[]
>   activationAttributes, Evidence
>   securityInfo, StackCrawlMark&
>   stackMark)    at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(String
>   assemblyName, String typeName)    at
>   System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String
>   assemblyName, String typeName)    at
>   System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String
>   assemblyName, String typeName)    at
>   System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String
>   assemblyName, String typeName)    at
>   MS.Internal.Package.VSIsolationProviderService.CreateIsolationProvider(String
>   identity, AssemblyReferenceProvider
>   assemblyReferences, IEnumerable`1
>   assemblyFolders)    at
>   MS.Internal.Providers.VSDesignerContext.GetIsolationProvider(IServiceProvider
>   provider, IVsHierarchy hierarchy,
>   AssemblyReferenceProvider
>   assemblyReferences, Boolean
>   isSilverlightProject)    at
>   MS.Internal.Providers.VSDesignerContext.GetIsolationProvider(IServiceProvider
>   provider, IVsHierarchy hierarchy,
>   AssemblyReferenceProvider
>   assemblyReferences)    at
>   MS.Internal.Providers.VSDesignerContext.Initialize(IServiceProvider
>   provider, IVsHierarchy hierarchy,
>   UInt32 itemid, Object docDataObj)
>   at
>   MS.Internal.Providers.VSDesignerContext..ctor(IServiceProvider
>   provider, IVsWindowFrame frame, Object
>   docDataObj)    at
>   MS.Internal.Providers.VSDesignerContext.GetContext(IServiceProvider
>   services, IVsWindowFrame frame,
>   Boolean createIfNotExist)    at
>   MS.Internal.Designer.DesignerPane.InitializeDesigner()

What I tried to this moment:

- Reset all settings in Visual Studio
- Closed any open XAML files in project, closed Visual Studio, re-opened VS, opened XAML file
- Create new user in operating system and try open solution with them
- Completed uninstallation/reinstallation of VS 2008 SP1 + MSDN, .NET 3.5 Framework SP1, Silverlight SDK, WPF Toolkit - January 2009

I run on Windows Vista SP1 32bit Business Edition.

Do any have a idea how can I solve it before I would try reinstalling operation system?

Regards
Anton Kalcik

UPDATE: Also I tried to disable all add-ons.

Answer (score 1):

First of all not only you receive this error so may be you should [google it first](http://www.google.com/search?q=Loading+this+assembly+would+produce+a+different+grant+set+from+other+instances&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)? As you can see there are many behaviors of this problem and we are not able to figure out what is wrong in your case because it's hard to reproduce the problem. Also you may try to repair you VS or [disable all your addins](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vswpfdesigner/thread/40e2b0a8-8131-4b50-a290-654f657c1d8e/)

Comment: I wouldn't write here, before I didn't tried everything I found to this time over Google. But for me isn't it more relevant. Because I need my VS intact, reinstalled my computer. But it can be interesting for another user with same problem.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Did you reinstalled it or just recovered? By the word, for such problems I suggest to contact support of MS, they may know more.

Comment: I reinstalled my computer completely. That was also good reason to throw Vista away :-). At this time I get better performance with XP.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for explaining what attempts failed. Saves me the hours and false hope.
Have you tried reinstalling VS without SP1? (You bet it's SP1's fault, this never happened before I updated VS)
Also your designer doesn't work on ANY project right? Even new ones? And in other prog languages too?

Comment: Yes I tried VS without SP1. My designer didn't work anywhere (I tried only C# projects)